# Is it worth using Twitter Bootstrap for a fully customised responsive design

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, css-frameworks

I am about to build a website using Asp.Net MVC.

I am trying to decide on which responsive framework to use and have been looking at several but am fundamentally stuck choosing between very simple (eg. Responsive Grid System) and fully featured (eg. Bootstrap).

The issue is that as far as html, css and javascript goes I pretty much know what I am doing so will use various js plugins if I need them to achieve any desired functionality.

We will not be using the standard button styles that Twitter provides and would probably need to customise many aspects of the Twitter widgets  and features - so is there still any advantage to using a more fully featured framework?

Comment: Sounds to me as if the only thing you'd be using Bootstrap for is the responsiveness.  I assume there is some time savings in having that done for you.  If you'll need customize the styles anyway, why not benefit from the framework?

Comment: Ya it is still worth.. even though you are not making use of those plugins and predefined styles,You can customize it fully using LESS(including the breakpoints for media query).It would surely save you time..You can also remove the unused plugins and elements during your download so that it doesnt keep your application bloating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to plug my own work (that's a lie) but my framework Jeet is perfect for this. Seems like you just need a solid responsive grid system so if you're not afraid of Stylus I invite you to fork [this CodePen](http://bit.ly/jeetfork) and toy around with it.

If it's not your cup of tea or you're more comfortable with other preprocessors (SCSS particularly) then I'd suggest Bourbon's Neat for a simple grid, or Singularity.gs for a really powerful grid.

Either way I'd suggest against "padding-based" grids like Bootstrap 3 and Foundation 4 as they essentially force you to create/nest extra elements inside of every element just for transparent gutters (something very common). It turns into way too much bloat.

Comment: This is very interesting but in fact watching your video, raises a whole area that I know very little about.  Which IDE are you using to put all of this together.  I use visual studio and asp.net mvc and pretty much hand code css and html. It would be good to have an IDE in whcih could use preprocessors like stylus or SCSS for all front-end work and use visual studio for the server side stuff.

Comment: The IDE has nothing to do with what preprocessor you're using. You could use Notepad.

CSS Preprocessors (LESS, SCSS, Stylus) all generally do the same thing, and they have command-line watchers that will watch for changes to the file (in this case, /css/custom.styl) and spit it out as CSS.

Sublime Text is more of a text editor than an IDE so if you're doing a lot of heavy development you might be better off with something like Visual Studio.

Long story short, use Visual Studio for your .NET stuff and have a command prompt watch the dir.

Comment: Thanks Cory - this has kind of opened up a whole new avenue. Off topic again but found a good free plugin (Mindscape Workbench) for VS but only for scss/sass/less.  Having been introduced now to Stylus, I much prefer the syntax - it just seems more natural. Have decided to go with a simpler framework rather than Zurb or Bootstrap. Thanks for the informative reply - I hope Jeet takes off - are you keeping track of take-up as a matter of interest?

Comment: I'm actually the creator/maintainer and part of a really strong/talented team that's working on it now so it'll be really strong pretty soon.

Comment: @Cory I find this really interesting. Do you have a site for Jeet so I can take look?